# Probability of getting a vowel

Tags: probability

The question is as follows:
A single letter is selected at random from the word "probability". What is the probability that the selected letter will be a vowel?

I know the question looks simple..........

My attempt:

$P(\mathrm{vowel}) = \frac 4{11}$ as there are $3$ vowels and total $9$ distinct letters... and "i" twice as well as "b".

But the answer given for it is $\frac 3 {11}$. $\frac 4{11}$ is incorrect! And please don't say, "consider both 'i' the same," because then sample space will decrease as there are $2$ b's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If each of the $11$ letters is equally likely to be chosen, then the probability of choosing a vowel is indeed $\frac 4{11}$. Is the wording of the question exactly as you worded it?

Comment: yes, it's the same!!

Comment: In the word "probability", the letter "y" serves as a vowel. See [english.stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10458/when-is-y-a-vowel). So, would that make it $\dfrac{5}{11}$?

Answer (score 1):

If you have copied the exact wording of the question, then the stated answer of 3/11 is incorrect. Your answer of 4/11 is indeed right.

Comment: U sure? Thanks!!

Comment: As @InterstellarProbe points out, the answer may actually be 5/11, depending on whether or not y is counted as a vowel (which it perhaps should be). But the answer is certainly *not* 3/11.